# Re-training OpenAI Fine-Tuned Chat-Bot Model: From Scratch or Can I Add New Data?

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently working on a Fine-Tuned model that a partner asked me to build for his website in order to use it as a AI powered Chat-Bot. My question is, can I go back to this model after I have built it for him and retrain it with new information as the website and the products change, or do I have to and train the model with the both the old and new data set all over again.

I am almost done with the data preparation to train the model.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.